# Meteor error in lib directory

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have the following code in my top-level meteorroot/lib directory:

//lib/collections/collectionsEnum.js

```
var collections = {};


COLLECTION_NAMES = Object.freeze({

  EmployeesCollection:{

    name:'EmployeesCollection',
    value: getMeteorCollectionByName(name)

  },

   FoodCollection:{

    name:'FoodCollection',
    value: getMeteorCollectionByName(name)

  },
    PlayerCollection:{

    name:'PlayerCollection',
    value: getMeteorCollectionByName(name)

  }


});


getMeteorCollectionByName = function(name){

  for(var coll in COLLECTION_NAMES){

    if(coll.name == name){

      if(collections.name === undefined){
        if(Meteor.isServer){
          collections.name = new Meteor.Collection(name);
          }
      }
      return collections.name;

    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I get this error when running >meteor

```
➜  oresoftware_meteor git:(master) ✗ meteor                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[[[[[ ~/code/oresoftware_meteor ]]]]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                

=> Started proxy.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206                                                                     
                                                throw(ex);         


Error: EACCES, readdir '/home/nitrous/code/oresoftware_meteor/lib/collections'                                                                                                                                                                       
  at Object.Future.wait (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)                                        
  at Object.wrapper (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/files.js:1124:24)                                                                         
  at readDirectory (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/watch.js:229:26)                                                                           
  at Object.readAndWatchDirectory (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/watch.js:650:18)                                                            
  at readAndWatchDirectory (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-source.js:1551:32)                                                         
  at [object Object].sourceArch.getSourcesFunc (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-source.js:1621:47)                                     
  at compileUnibuild (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:291:37)     
at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:135:26                                                                                        
  at Array.forEach (native)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)                          
  at Object.compiler.compile (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:131:5)                                                               
  at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2023:24                                                                                        
  at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:264:13                                                                                    
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)                                              
  at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:257:29                                                                                            
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)                                              
  at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:255:18                                                                                    
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)                                              
  at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:246:23                                                                                    
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)                                              
  at Object.capture (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:19)                                                                   
  at Object.exports.bundle (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1975:31) 
 at bundleApp (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:508:34)                                                                             
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:544:35)                                                     
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:771:28)                                                       
  at /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:366:12                                                                                         

    - - - - -
```

the Object.freeze() call and the isMeteor() call don't seem to be causing the problem. I did the isMeteor call because I don't believe you are supposed to call new Meteor.Collection() from the client, but I'd have to triple check that.

Answer (score 1):

An `EACCES` error means you don't have permissions to perform the current file operation. This usually happens after you run or modify something in your project as root. Try:

```
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER [filename]
```

In your case, this would look like:

```
$ sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/nitrous/code/oresoftware_meteor/lib/collections
```

If you get more `EACCES` errors, you may need to `chown` your whole directory with:

```
$ cd /home/nitrous/code/oresoftware_meteor
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

Comment: I believe it's capital -R not -r for recursive eh? I tried this - unfortunately same error occurred :(

Comment: my best guest is that it was error between Nitrous.io and Ubuntu, I don't think Nitrous was playing nice with the file system as I had too files open with the same name, because I had deleted one, but Nitrous still had the deleted one open. that's all I got right now. restarted Nitrous, moved files around, seems to work.

Comment: Interesting. I'm glad you got it figured out. :)

Comment: I think it's a problem with Nitrous.io, haven't had problems with it til now